# Merge center in ssrs

Tags: python, excel, reporting-services, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-paginated-reports

I have three column name

| SLno | State | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Punjab | 2024-1-2 |
| 2 | Punjab | 2024-1-2 |
| 3 | Assam | 2024-1-8 |
| 4 | Assam | 2024-1-7 |
| 5 | UP | 2024-1-14 |
| 6 | UP | 2024-1-13 |

How to merge exactly in where state is there.
how to achieve it in SSRS Report.
[image]

Comment: can anybody resolve this issue?

Comment: Can anybody help me?

Comment: commenting on your own post trying to bump it won't resolve anything. If people can help they will. The short answer is that you cannot do this simply, you cannot have a grouped column with non-grouped columns on both sides and you cannot merge rows like this. The only way to do it might be to use a subreport with a single text box aligned as you want but it seems overkill just to align a text box. Or just have state as the first column and group on it.

Comment: What is the original data, just text? and you want to dump into Excel  with the State cells merged as shown in the screen shot?

Comment: Sl No        State   Date
-------- --------- --------- 
1           Punjab    2023-01-01  
2           Punjab    2023-02-01
3           Assam     2023-03-01
4           Assam     2023-04-01
5           UP           2023-05-01
6           UP           2023-06-01

Same format i want to in Power bi Report builder